# Build AWS Java Lambda with Gradle, use shadowJar or buildZip for archive to upload?

Tags: amazon-web-services, gradle, aws-lambda

**Description**

I am developing [AWS Java Lambdas](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-programming-model.html), with [Gradle](https://gradle.org) as my build tool.

AWS requires a "self-contained" Java archive (.jar, .zip, ...) to be uploaded, which has to include everything, my source code, the dependencies etc.

There is the Gradle plugin [shadow](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/) for this purpose, it can be included like this:

```
import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.transformers.Log4j2PluginsCacheFileTransformer

...

shadowJar { 
  archiveName = "${project.name}.jar"
  mergeServiceFiles()
  transform(Log4j2PluginsCacheFileTransformer)  
}
build.dependsOn shadowJar
```

*gradle build* produces a file *somefunction.jar*, in my case it is 9.5MB in size.

AWS documentation [suggests](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/best-practices.html) to

> putting your dependency .jar files in a separate /lib directory

There are specific instructions how to do this on [Creating a ZIP Deployment Package for a Java Function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/create-deployment-pkg-zip-java.html).

```
task buildZip(type: Zip) {
  archiveName = "${project.name}.zip"
  from compileJava
  from processResources
  into('lib') {
    from configurations.runtimeClasspath
  }
}
build.dependsOn buildZip
```

*gradle build* produces a file *build/distributions/somefunction.zip*, in my case it is 8.5MB in size.

Both archives, zip and jar, can be upload to AWS and run fine. Performance seems to be the same.

**Question**

Which archive to favor, Zip or (shdow)Jar?

More specific questions, which come to my mind:

- [AWS documetation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/best-practices.html) says "This [putting your dependency .jar files in a separate /lib directory] is faster than putting all your function’s code in a single jar with a large number of .class files." Does anyone know, what exactly is faster? Build-time? Cold/warm start? Execution time?
- When build the Zip, I am not using the shadowJar features [mergeServiceFiles()](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/configuration/merging/#merging-service-descriptor-files) and *Log4j2PluginsCacheFileTransformer*. Not using mergeServiceFiles should in worst case decrease the execution time. As long as I omit [Log4j2 plugins](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/plugins.html), I can omit Log4j2PluginsCacheFileTransformer. Right?
- Are there any performance considerations using the one or the other?

Comment: I've used both methods for packaging zip files, and both have worked.   Initially I used "Spring Cloud Functions" with led me to use shadowJars so I could execute the code locally before deploying to AWS.  I decided that was not worth the overhead as deploying to lambda was quite quick, not saving much time in development cycle.  I've not noticed a difference in performance  between the two methods, but in the end I've used the zip-with-libs solution as a) Amazon suggests it, b) feels aesthetically cleaner/simpler method.